# Conformer generation for radicals

Tags: organic-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, conformers

Is there an automatic way to generate conformers for radical like systems (spin multiplicity is doublet)? My system for the study is a substituted fullerene with a missing H atom from the functional group.

I have tried using different conformer generators for this purpose (Baloon, RDKit, Obabel, Fullmonte, CCDC's Conformer_generator) but none of them successfully yielded out any conformers. I do not know how to run MD of such a system for which there is no general force-filed available. I have also tried to go through the AMBER tutorial but was unsuccessful: http://ambermd.org/tutorials/basic/tutorial4b/

I would really appreciate if anyone can suggest something that actually works for the system in consideration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that a non-reactive MD calculation would be meaningful for a radical system?

Comment: I recommend gfn2-xtb from the Grimme group: https://www.chemie.uni-bonn.de/pctc/mulliken-center/software/xtb/xtb I have not tried the `confscript` yet, but the `siman` option works reasonable well for my systems.

Comment: RDKit should work. Can you post the code somewhere (e.g. https://gist.github.com)?  This code should also work for you https://github.com/jensengroup/get_conformations

Comment: Just saw this - can you post the compound? I'm surprised that OB (and others) don't see "conformers" and it's possible that your structure falls beyond the usual rules. I'll post more later.

Answer (score 3):

## tldr: Manually or script dihedral angle changes, then use a GFN or another DFTB method to find any/all conformers

Without seeing the compound, it's really hard to know the problem. *Most* programs, including those you mentioned, have a set of rules to identify "rotatable bonds" and suggest likely dihedral angles.

As you might expect, such rules are derived for neutral, ground-state organic molecules.

There are a few options:

- As suggested by Jan Jensen's comments above, you can use RDKit, Open Babel or another tool to drive your own dihedral angle search.
- As suggested by Martin's comments above, there are some tools in Grimme's `xtb`  program to sample conformations. These will use the GFN1 or GFN2 approximate density functional (pretty much DFTB + dispersion correction) to evaluate energies.

I'd probably suggest a combination of both. From what I understand of Grimme's conformer search scripts, it calculates the vibrational modes of the molecule and samples geometries along vibrational modes. This is a good idea, although in some molecules it may not sample all minima (e.g., if you have many conformations in a large molecule, you might never "reach" the whole potential energy surface from any given initial geometry).

So you can change the dihedral angles using your program of choice, generate a few initial structures, then use `xtb` to optimize the geometries and `confscript` to sample a few more geometries.

I feel pretty confident that in small to medium geometry molecules, this will do a good job.

A few notes:

- If you're sampling a radical, you definitely want to use a good DFT or quantum method to evaluate the energies. I doubt any current force field will do what you want.
- We haven't finished our evaluation, but right now, GFN2 is performing better than any current method on conformer energetics for neutral organic molecules. We haven't checked radicals, but I would trust it more than any other current "fast" method.
- If you don't have the `xtb` package, the method and conformer sampling scripts are now available as part of `ORCA` 4.1 too. There's a description of this kind of conformer sampling in the manual when discussing prediction of NMR spectra.

Comment: Your question is a great illustration of why my group is currently working on a "conformer toolbox" - an NSF-funded project to create a set of easy-to-use software for generating many kinds of conformers. I'll come back and revise when we have some better tools for problems like this.